# 2 ObservableCollections 1 Combobox WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, observablecollection

I have a WPF application, that establishes a connection to a different computer. Inside my application, I have a combo box, where the user can enter a hostname of a computer and then connect to this computer. Now once the connection was established the hostname the user entered gets saved into an Observable Collection which is bound to the combo box, so the next time he wants to connect to the same host, he can choose it directly from the combo box.

I have implemented a favorite list. which is a separate observable collection that I too want to bind to the same combo box, so the user can either choose either a favorite or a history item.

In the dropdown list of the combo box I would like 2 Groupings with a Header, something like this:

```cs
    [Favorites]
         My Favourite Host | myfavhost.com
         My 2nd Fav | my2ndfav.com
         Secretly My Fav | secretlymyfav.com
    [History]
         hostioncevisited.com
         whyamihere.com
         thanksforhelping.com
```

Now I don't really know how to go about that. Is there a way to bind multiple items sources to the combobox, or would I have to merge the two observable collections before I bind them to the combo box?

These are my observable collections

```cs
public ObservableCollection<string> HistoryItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public static ObservableCollection<FavoriteItem> FavoriteItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<FavoriteItem>();
```

Here is my FavoriteItem Class

```cs
public class FavoriteItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private string hostName;
        private string description;

        public FavoriteItem(){}
        public FavoriteItem(string _hostName, string _description)
        {
            hostName = _hostName;
            description = _description;
        }

        public string Hostname
        {
            get { return hostName; }
            set
            {
                hostName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Hostname");
            }
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get { return description; }
            set
            {
                description = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} | {1}", description, hostName);
        }
    }
```

Here is the XAML for the combo box

XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="cbHostName" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxLarge}" Text="{Binding HostName}" ItemsSource="{Binding HistoryItems}" 
                          MinWidth="300" MaxWidth="300" IsEditable="True" Margin="0,0,15,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Computer, IP or HostProfileName"/>
```

Comment: You may use a CompositeCollection. Not sure if it works with grouping.

Comment: These don't seem like two collections, but more like a single collection that has a property that indicates it as a favorite.  Would a host that shows up in the favorite list also be in the history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CompositeCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-a-compositecollection) to bind multiple collections to the same source.

[Here is an example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Combining-item-sources-in-65408473).

The disadvantage is that I don't think grouping is possible in this scenario (at least not easily).

---

**The alternative** would be to have only one list, of objects implementing the same interface, with some property to distinguish type of item, e.g.:

```
public interface IHost : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string HostType { get; }
    string Hostname { get; set; }
    string DisplayText { get; set; }
}

public class HistoryItem : IHost
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string HostType => "History";
    public string Hostname { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText => Hostname;
}

public class FavoriteItem : IHost
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string HostType => "Favorites";
    public string Hostname { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText => Description == null ? Hostname : $"{Description} | {Hostname}";
    //other properties....
}
```

As I find working directly with `ObservableCollection` annoying, I tend to use a wrapper for it (code at the bottom). It deals with some common issues, such as possible memory leaks and raising `CollectionChanged` events unnecessary while adding multiple items. It also provides easy access to grouping, sorting, filtering, current item and `CurrentChanged` & `CurrentChanging` events from codebehind.

In ViewModel:

```
public ViewableCollection<IHost> MyItems { get; set; }
```

Initializing the collection:

```
this.MyItems  = new ViewableCollection<IHost>();

// decide how your items will be sorted (important: first sort groups, then items in groups)
this.MyItems.View.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("HostType", ListSortDirection.Ascending)); // sorting of groups
this.MyItems.View.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Hostname", ListSortDirection.Ascending)); // sorting of items

PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("HostType");
this.MyItems.View.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);

this.MyItems.View.CurrentChanged += MyItems_CurrentChanged;

this.MyItems.AddRange(new IHost[] {
           new HistoryItem { Hostname = "ccc" },
           new HistoryItem { Hostname = "aaa" },
           new HistoryItem { Hostname = "xxx" },
           new FavoriteItem { Hostname = "vvv" },
           new FavoriteItem { Hostname = "bbb" },
           new FavoriteItem { Hostname = "ttt" } });
```

This code will execute when the item is selected:

```
private void MyItems_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Selected item: " + this.MyItems.CurrentItem?.Hostname);
    }
```

Here is the xaml of `ComboBox` with grouping (using `ViewableCollection`, you need to bind `ItemsSource` to  `MyItems.View` instead of directly to `MyItems`):

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems.View, Mode=OneWay}"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText">
        <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Items.CurrentItem.HostType, StringFormat=[{0}]}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
    </ComboBox>
```

result:

[image: combo box code result]

---

```
[DoNotNotify]
public class ViewableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private ListCollectionView _View;

    public ViewableCollection(IEnumerable<T> items)
        : base(items) { }

    public ViewableCollection()
        : base() { }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public ListCollectionView View
    {
        get
        {
            if (_View == null)
            {
                _View = new ListCollectionView(this);
                _View.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(InnerView_CurrentChanged);
            }
            return _View;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public T CurrentItem
    {
        get
        {
            return (T)this.View.CurrentItem;
        }
        set
        {
            this.View.MoveCurrentTo(value);
        }
    }

    private void InnerView_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentItem"));
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        if (range == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("range");

        foreach (T item in range)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item);
        }

        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void ReplaceItems(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        if (range == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("range");

        this.Items.Clear();
        foreach (T item in range)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item);
        }

        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void RemoveItems(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {

        if (range == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("range");

        foreach (T item in range)
        {
            this.Items.Remove(item);
        }

        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void ClearAll()
    {
        IList old = this.Items.ToList();
        base.Items.Clear();
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void CallCollectionChaged()
    {
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    // necessary for xml easy serialization using [XmlArray] attribute
    public static implicit operator List<T>(ViewableCollection<T> o)
    {
        return o == null ? default(List<T>) : o.ToList();
    }

    // necessary for xml easy serialization using [XmlArray] attribute
    public static implicit operator ViewableCollection<T>(List<T> o)
    {
        return o == default(List<T>) || o == null ? new ViewableCollection<T>() : new ViewableCollection<T>(o);
    }
}
```

---

The above code is a working example. I'm using nuget package [PropertyChanged2.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PropertyChanged2.Fody/) to inject `PropertyChanged` notifications.

Answer (score -2):

No you cannot bind multiple collections to ItemsSource, you have to merge them